# Repository Pattern and SOLID principles

Tags: c#, repository, .net-core

I have written the following Repository in C#, using NetCore 2.2 and EF Core.

I was thinking how to write properly the Search method according to the SOLID principles.

This code gives a null reference exception when "Title" or "Genre" property is null. It means I will need to put an if to check for null values, and in that case, it does not respect the single responsibility principle: as this method is returning a set of elements from the DB and also making some operations with strings.

How can I refactor this to avoid null exception and respect the SRP?

```
public class MovieRepository: IMovieRepository
{
    private readonly MovieDbContext _moviesDbContext;
    public MovieRepository(MovieDbContext moviesDbContext)
    {
        _moviesDbContext = moviesDbContext;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Movie> GetAll()
    {
        return _moviesDbContext.Movies;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Movie> Search(MovieFilters filters)
    {
        var title = filters.Title.ToLower();
        var genre = filters.Genre.ToLower();
        return _moviesDbContext.Movies.Where( 
             p => (p.Title.Trim().ToLower().Contains(title) | string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p.Title))
             & (p.Genre.Trim().ToLower().Contains(genre) | string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p.Genre))
             & (p.YearOfRelease == filters.YearOfRelease | filters.YearOfRelease == null)
           );
    }
}
```

And this is the code that works in case of null values but I don't know how to refactor this according to with SOLID, I will appreciate some ideas to move those IFs sentences:

```
public IEnumerable<Movie> Search(MovieFilters filters)
{
    string title = "";
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filters.Title) == false)
    {
        title = filters.Title.ToLower();
    }

    string genre = "";
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filters.Genre) == false)
    {
        genre = filters.Genre.ToLower();
    }

    return _moviesDbContext.Movies.Where( p => (p.Title.Trim().ToLower().Contains(title) | string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p.Title))
                                               & (p.Genre.Trim().ToLower().Contains(genre) | string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p.Genre))
                                               & (p.YearOfRelease == filters.YearOfRelease | filters.YearOfRelease == null)
                                        );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference between & and && as well as | and ||. There is a null coalescing operator ?. and ?? that you can use and string equals method has a second parameter where you can pass StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase.

The lambda could look like:

```
o => p.Title?.Trim().Equals(title ?? "", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) 
  || p.Genre?.Trim().Equals(genre ?? "", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

What the SOLID means is that you pass that in a an argument to a method like

```
public IEnumerable<T> Search<T>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
    return _dbContext.Set<T>()
           .Where(predicate)
           .AsEnumerable();
}
```

and it would not contain your validation checks or business logic.

Comment: Regarding the || in the lambda expressions, is not what I want, I would like all the conditions to be checked: so if the movie title has something and also the genre I want to apply the filter for both conditions. Not sure if I understood well you code.